# How to set oracle CONNECTION_PROPERTY_NET_KEEPALIVE property in Java

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection, keep-alive

I am getting sudden drops in connection in my java application when connection has been idle for sometime.

```
IO Error: Connection reset; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException
```

Found below:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html

How to set keep alive property in Java?

Comment: From your link: _"All connection properties can be specified as a URL parameter. Most connection properties can be specified as a system property, as a Properties object entry, or as a properties file entry."_ This would suggest that adding `oracle.net.keepAlive=true` as a connection property to the URL, or to the `Properties` object should work.

Comment: Refer to OracleConnection.html (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html). These connection properties can be passed as system property, through a Properties object or as part of the connection URL. Look at "Using TNS alias section of the blog" (https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/four-facets-of-database-connectivity-for-java-applications#TNS) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This might "work" for you but unfortunately Linux kernel default values are not practical.

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
7200
```

Delay before the 1st probe is sent - 2 hours.
NOTE: the default value for CISCO ASA's "connection timeout idle" is just 1 hour!!! So the connection is killed before 1st keepalive probe is sent. Unfortunately you need root to change this kernel parameter. Java so far does not support per TCP connection ioctl command to set keepalive parameters.

When you change this kernel parameter you should see something like this:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
75
Interval between probes.

# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
9
The number of "lost" probes indicating that the connection is dead.
```

On Oracle side Oracle TCP Keepalive is not active for oracle connections by default. It can be turned on by setting `(ENABLE=BROKEN)` under DESCRIPTION element in connect string or by using `-Doracle.net.keepAlive=true`

You can verify your setting by using tcpdump
Connect using:

```
(DESCRIPTION=
    (ENABLE=BROKEN)
    (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=90)
    (RETRY_COUNT=20)
    (FAILOVER=ON)
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rac-cluster-scan)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ACTEST))
)

[~]# nslookup rac-cluster-scan 
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   rac-cluster-scan
Address: 192.168.8.209

[~]# ip route get 192.168.8.209
192.168.8.209 dev ens224 src 192.168.8.200
    cache

[~]# tcpdump -pni ens224 -v "tcp port 1521 and ( tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-ack != 0 and ( (ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2) ) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2) ) == 0 )"
tcpdump: listening on ens224, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
14:56:49.994675 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12096, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.8.200.37196 > 192.168.8.212.ncube-lm: Flags [.], cksum 0x9313 (incorrect -> 0x4b94), ack 2263270845, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 78140944 ecr 7133273], length 0
14:56:49.994829 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55327, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.8.212.ncube-lm > 192.168.8.200.37196: Flags [.], cksum 0xadcf (correct), ack 1, win 207, options [nop,nop,TS val 7138281 ecr 78110940], length 0
14:56:55.002668 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12097, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.8.200.37196 > 192.168.8.212.ncube-lm: Flags [.], cksum 0x9313 (incorrect -> 0x2474), ack 1, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 78145952 ecr 7138281], length 0
14:56:55.002809 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55328, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.8.212.ncube-lm > 192.168.8.200.37196: Flags [.], cksum 0x9a3f (correct), ack 1, win 207, options [nop,nop,TS val 7143289 ecr 78110940], length 0
14:57:00.010680 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12098, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.8.200.37196 > 192.168.8.212.ncube-lm: Flags [.], cksum 0x9313 (incorrect -> 0xfd53), ack 1, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 78150960 ecr 7143289], length 0
14:57:00.011296 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55329, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.8.212.ncube-lm > 192.168.8.200.37196: Flags [.], cksum 0x86af (correct), ack 1, win 207, options [nop,nop,TS val 7148297 ecr 78110940], length 0

6 packets captured
6 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

When you change keepalive parameter on kernel level, this tcpdump filter should display probes sent at requested interval.

PS: TCP keepalive sending is solely handled by Linux kernel. Oracle's client SW can only turn this option on, when opening connection.